# Negative reputation of users in review audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, review-audits

I was reviewing posts today and got the following post to review:

> [image]

Note how the user has negative reputation.

If I may add "seems legit".

Comment: Can you show the link please?

Comment: @hims056 http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2532622 - Although that won't do you much good because once the audit is completed it returns to real values.

Comment: @hims056 Sure - http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2532622

Comment: @animuson - Ahh, I didn't read review *audit*. :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've had that happen also

Comment: Anybody who misses that is certainly not looking at the screen while reviewing and should be suspended instantaneously.

Comment: @AsheeshR: I disagree, I *rarely* look at the user card when doing review (either via queue or frontpage). It's just an information I don't need when making my decision.

Comment: **+1** That happened to me just yesterday.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That was really a bit too obvious. Fixed in builds 2013.7.18.1231 (meta), 2013.7.18.859 (sites).

Comment: Thanks, to be honest I'm surprised you fixed it so fast :) Good work.